# Error with request using auth0 JWT token in Angular

Tags: angular, auth0

Problem with request when using auth0 JWT token in Angular.

I'm use angular2-jwt by Auth0

Scenario: I have an angled application using JWT Auth0 working perfectly, but I have discovered a request problem. When I log in to another application that uses XSRF-TOKEN in the browser, my application stops working and no longer supplies the correct header.

Request Headers

```
> Accept:application/json, text/plain, */* Accept-Encoding:gzip,
> deflate, br Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
> Authorization:JWT
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTA1MTYwNDU1LCJlbWFpbCI6InN1cG9ydGVAbXd0aS5jb20uYnIifQ.HK7nxI3ZTMbtczKKFNwduMqfUCsSDPnR9ROKoFbIbaw
> Connection:keep-alive Content-Length:51 Content-Type:application/json
> Host:127.0.0.1:8000 Origin:http://localhost:4200
> Referer:http://localhost:4200/login User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
> Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

Now the request when there is an XSRF-TOKEN inside the cookie

```
> Accept:*/* Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
> Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,x-xsrf-token
> Access-Control-Request-Method:GET Connection:keep-alive
> Host:127.0.0.1:8000 Origin:http://localhost:4200
> Referer:http://localhost:4200/login User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
> Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

When an XSRF-TOKEN exists my header with JWT is not sent and replaced.

Comment: Don't know if you read this, but they mention it : https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/. Don't know how to protect against them tho